# How evenly distribute Mongodb shard if I have more record in one range?

Tags: mongodb, sharding

[image]

Based on the above image If I have more records that comes under 20. Shard C will have more records,will this make any performance issue?  How can I improve the performance.

In my case I am facing performance issue? How can I resolve that?

Comment: The diagram you referenced illustrates the general concept of shard key ranges (aka *chunks* in MongoDB terminology), but you should review the full documentation on [Ranged Sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/ranged-sharding/) for more context. Your shard key ranges will [automatically split](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/#chunk-splits) based on data inserts and updates, and chunks will be [migrated](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/sharding-data-partitioning/#chunk-migration) to have a balanced distribution across shards.

Comment: If  you have a performance problem to investigate, I suggest posting a question on [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/mongodb) (which is more on-topic for database admin) including details such as your MongoDB server version,  shard key, and the performance problem you are trying to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

First off, Determine a primary key to shard your database on

For your understanding, if `x` is unique for your docs, then you can use something like a `x%3` technique (**as an example**) to distribute the data evenly among 3 shards.

MongoDB supports 2 ways of sharding and for evenly distributing in your case [Hashed sharding](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/#hashed-sharding) will be the better pick.

`sh.shardCollection( "database.collection", { <field> : "hashed" } )`

MongoDB takes care of  computing the hashes when resolving queries using hashed indexes and your application will not need to compute hashes